# MVC5 WebSecurity, use secondary database temporarily

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have a solution with two MVC projects.  The first is a management system, the second is a portal for contractors.  I want to manage the contractor login of the portal via the main application.

The membership database for both projects is identical in schema (the default).  My thought was to hijack the main system's Register action, swap out the connection string, register the contractor user in its' own database, then swap the connection string back to the main one.

I'm guessing this won't work, namely based on the fact that `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()` can only be called once.

Thus my question: if I want to call the `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount()` method but point it to a different database than what it was originally initialized for, how would I do so?

I looked at the built-in `InitializeSimpleMembership` filter for clues, but am not seeing the path I'm looking for.

Is this even a feasible approach?

Alternatively, if I can get the password hashed per the same way it's done by default, it looks like I can enter the required data to the db manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I can manually work this out.  According to the msdn docs for `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount()`:

> This method creates a new entry in the user profile table and then a corresponding entry in the membership table. The ID of the membership entry is based on the ID of the user profile entry. (The IDs of the entries in the two tables match.)

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.createuserandaccount(v=vs.111).aspx)

Inspecting the database schema shows that I only need two tables for this, and the fields are straigtforward.

To hash the password according to the same way the `SimpleMembershipProvider` does, I can use the `System.Web.Helpers.Crypo.HashPassword()` method.

This simplifies the basic account creation considerably as I don't have to piggyback off the AccountController and can just write these directly to the db and call it good (for my purposes, anyway, not requiring verification tokens and having seperately handled email notifications).  On the portal side, the built-in SimpleMembershipProvider should be able to handle everything as usual.